# Callback from Native Library to JNI Interface

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

How can i call a function from native library to JNI interface, and how can i call a function from JNI interface to the JAVA? Is that possible? how can i do that?

Below is JNI Interface(Assumption)

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_test_mode_calltoJava(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {

/*Call to Java Function */
}
```

Below is C library function(Assumption)

```
void test(int a,int b){
           Call to JNI Interface
          //Java_com_example_test_mode_calltoJava(a,b)
}
```

**NOTE:** My framework is like this : [C Library] <---> [ JNI Interface ] <---> [ JAVA ], i need to register a callback in C Library from JNI Interface, then when appropriate event occurs in my C Library the registered callback should call the JAVA function.